# 1:n relationships in Azure and Xamarin

Tags: entity-framework, azure, xamarin, entity-framework-6

I am working on the following tables :

1. `BadgesGroup` table: contains a list of badges that are grouped together -> group A have badge 1 and 2 , Gruop B have badge 3 and 4 ...etc also contain information such as group logo
2. `Badges` table: contains information about a specific badge such as title and description
3. `CustomerBadges` table: contains the progress of each badge and to which customer it belong to

Following this tutorial :
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuremobile/2014/05/27/retrieving-data-from-1n-relationship-using-net-backend-azure-mobile-services/

I managed to work it out successfully and retrieve all information of a given group with one API request.

Example :

```
[
    {
        "deleted": false,
        "updatedAt": null,
        "createdAt": "2019-07-07T17:47:32.043Z",
        "version": "AAAAAAAAJyQ=",
        "id": "4CD03F1F-BDB2-47BC-9084-35B5DF7E1530",
        "levels": 4,
        "logo": "img.png",
        "badges": [
            {
                "customerBadge": [
                    {
                        "progress": 1,
                        "id": "037EC616-A17C-4E89-B4F5-F4DE960AB3B5",
                        "version": "AAAAAAAAJz4=",
                        "createdAt": "2019-07-07T17:51:21.253Z",
                        "updatedAt": null,
                        "deleted": false
                    }
                ],
                "title": "Noob",
                "description": "redeem 1",
                "currentLevel": 1,
                "id": "0F63CFD2-6679-4D25-AB40-280003555676",
                "version": "AAAAAAAAJyw=",
                "createdAt": "2019-07-07T17:48:24.429Z",
                "updatedAt": null,
                "deleted": false
            },
            {
                "customerBadge": [
                    {
                        "progress": 4,
                        "id": "545B769C-FCA1-4C5D-BB5A-4D31BD724340",
                        "version": "AAAAAAAAJ0Q=",
                        "createdAt": "2019-07-07T17:51:32.035Z",
                        "updatedAt": null,
                        "deleted": false
                    }
                ],
                "title": "King",
                "description": "redeem 4",
                "currentLevel": 4,
                "id": "39E8E825-9196-43BC-890A-7E7833615818",
                "version": "AAAAAAAAJy0=",
                "createdAt": "2019-07-07T17:49:45.13Z",
                "updatedAt": null,
                "deleted": false
            },
            {
                "customerBadge": [
                    {
                        "progress": 3,
                        "id": "24E30749-78A5-4AA9-B097-073C8E7162FD",
                        "version": "AAAAAAAAJ0Y=",
                        "createdAt": "2019-07-07T17:51:40.076Z",
                        "updatedAt": null,
                        "deleted": false
                    }
                ],
                "title": "Master",
                "description": "Redeem 3",
                "currentLevel": 3,
                "id": "935FE343-A6EC-43DD-8E50-6461A69CC757",
                "version": "AAAAAAAAJy4=",
                "createdAt": "2019-07-07T17:49:22.741Z",
                "updatedAt": null,
                "deleted": false
            },
            {
                "customerBadge": [
                    {
                        "progress": 2,
                        "id": "0723DB30-D7AF-41C5-8E6F-3B3A174805B9",
                        "version": "AAAAAAAAJ0U=",
                        "createdAt": "2019-07-07T17:51:15.04Z",
                        "updatedAt": null,
                        "deleted": false
                    }
                ],
                "title": "Pro",
                "description": "redeem 2",
                "currentLevel": 2,
                "id": "9E169884-11FC-4893-8465-3D4792CCEEBC",
                "version": "AAAAAAAAJy8=",
                "createdAt": "2019-07-07T17:49:05.011Z",
                "updatedAt": null,
                "deleted": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "deleted": false,
        "updatedAt": null,
        "createdAt": "2019-07-07T17:47:53.101Z",
        "version": "AAAAAAAAJyU=",
        "id": "602BBB5D-06D4-4685-AB65-5514CA73884B",
        "levels": 2,
        "logo": "img2.png",
        "badges": [
            {
                "customerBadge": [
                    {
                        "progress": 22,
                        "id": "C236C1AB-37DC-47C9-B0CF-2825A916E77E",
                        "version": "AAAAAAAAJ0g=",
                        "createdAt": "2019-07-07T17:51:26.765Z",
                        "updatedAt": null,
                        "deleted": false
                    }
                ],
                "title": "Old",
                "description": "buy 4",
                "currentLevel": 2,
                "id": "74818583-1BC3-4FC5-81A2-4846C752CC8E",
                "version": "AAAAAAAAJzE=",
                "createdAt": "2019-07-07T17:50:23.947Z",
                "updatedAt": null,
                "deleted": false
            },
            {
                "customerBadge": [
                    {
                        "progress": 11,
                        "id": "6D541809-1775-49AA-83AE-F434E3CC0E08",
                        "version": "AAAAAAAAJ0c=",
                        "createdAt": "2019-07-07T17:51:07.33Z",
                        "updatedAt": null,
                        "deleted": false
                    }
                ],
                "title": "New",
                "description": "buy 1",
                "currentLevel": 1,
                "id": "81DE6DFB-D6F8-49D6-A62B-3F5AF018DE40",
                "version": "AAAAAAAAJzA=",
                "createdAt": "2019-07-07T17:50:09.621Z",
                "updatedAt": null,
                "deleted": false
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

These are my models in the Azure backend using C# and one Azure mobile controller named `AchievementGroupController` auto generated  :

```
public class AchievementGroup : EntityData
{
    public AchievementGroup()
    {
       Badges = new List<Badge>();
    }

    public string Logo { get; set; }
    public int Levels { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Badge> Badges { get; set; }
}

public class Badge : EntityData
{
    public Badge()
    {
        CustomerBadge = new List<CustomerBadge>();
    }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public int CurrentLevel { get; set; }
    public virtual AchievementGroup AchievementGroup { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CustomerBadge> CustomerBadge { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerBadge : EntityData
{
    public int Progress { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Badge Badge { get; set; }
}
```

Now what my issue is I can not distinguish which customer has which progress.

I want to tell the API give me All badge groups and their progress for this given customer.

Comment: I don't quite understand the meaning of some fields. Why are you have the groups  and the child items(group A have badge 1 and 2 , Gruop B have badge 3 and 4 ...etc)?  And what's the meaning of some model fields("id": "4CD03F1F-BDB2-47BC-9084-35B5DF7E1530",
        "levels": 4    and  "progress": 2,
                        "id": "0723DB30-D7AF-41C5-8E6F-3B3A174805B9")?

Comment: @JessieZhang  An achievement contain many levels , each level is a badge .
think of it like this way : Pizza newbie -> buy two pizzas (level 1) ; Pizza pro -> buy four pizzas (level 2) ; Pizza master -> buy 6 pizzas (level 3). now thats one group. another group will be something like this : Burger newbie -> but two burgers ( level 1) ; burger pro -> buy four burgers ... etc .
so levels tells how many badges in one group .

Comment: @JessieZhang the id field is the primary key using GUID .

progress tracks the badge of the customer , lets say you bought your first pizza , the application will track that and show you that you have one more pizza to buy to unlock pizza newbie badge and so on .

Comment: Well,according to my understanding,  I couldn't see any infromation relative to customer .

Comment: @JessieZhang Sorry my Mistake there is a column in the CustomerBadges Table with foreign key named CustomerID , i forgot to type it in .